# Setting Extension as Homepage via Button Click: Possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to enable users to set a new tab-opening extension as their homepage simply by clicking a button within the extension? If so, what would be the recommended approach to achieve this functionality in a secure and user-friendly manner?

I have implemented a button within my extension that, when clicked, currently displays an alert guiding users on how to manually set the extension's new tab page as their homepage in the browser settings.
I was hoping to explore if there's a more automated solution to allow users to set the extension as their homepage directly through the button click, considering the security restrictions in place.

Comment: please share some code, and what you've done so far